# Possible to obtain Contacts and Leads with their child relationships in one query/search?

Tags: soql, rest-api, sosl

I would like to obtain all contacts and leads that match an email address but also include their related child objects (e.g. activity histories) all in one query or one search. I can't figure out a way to do this, is it possible?

The reason behind it is that we're looking to execute this as fast as possible so cutting 2 API queries down to 1 would be very beneficial.

Another requirement is that we cannot modify the fields or add join objects to facilitate this so adding a relationship between Contacts/Leads is not an option.

I know how to do it using 2 SOQL queries:

```
SELECT Id, Email, Name, (SELECT Id, Subject FROM ActivityHistories),  (SELECT Id, Subject FROM OpenActivities) FROM Contact WHERE Email='bob@example.com'
SELECT Id, Email, Name, (SELECT Id, Subject FROM ActivityHistories),  (SELECT Id, Subject FROM OpenActivities) FROM Lead WHERE Email='bob@example.com'
```

What I'm looking for is some way to search across both so ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
FIND {bob@example.com} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING 
  Contact(Id, Email, Name, (SELECT Id, Subject FROM ActivityHistories),  (SELECT Id, Subject FROM OpenActivities)),
     Lead(Id, Email, Name, (SELECT Id, Subject FROM ActivityHistories),  (SELECT Id, Subject FROM OpenActivities))
```

As I understand though, SOSL does not allow you to include relationship queries in the return fields.

If this is not possible from standard SOSL/SOQL, is it possible to do this with the Batch API? Can I run the above 2 SOQL queries over the batch API instead?

Comment: Yes, you need two queries. There's no such thing as `Batch API`.

Comment: My mistake, I meant a [batch request](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm). Thanks for answering